# Java script array with php, fetch array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, fetch

I am trying to fetch latitude, longitude and venue by using

```
sites[0] // gets latitude
sites[1] // gets longitude
sites[2] // gets venue
```

This is my code, don't mind the sql queries, I know they are bad but it's functional for now. I just need help with this array:

```
  var sites = [<?php

include_once'config/connect.php';

$search= $_POST['search'];
$search = stripslashes($search);

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

$sql= "select * from venue where vID in (select vID from sv where sID in (select sID from sports where sN = '$search'));";

$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error()); 

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo ",[".$data['latitude']."]";
    echo ",[".$data['longitude']."]";
    echo ",[".$data['venue']."]";

}

?> ];
```

Comment: So what do you want and what error are you getting?

Comment: i want to get for example latitude if i type sites[0] but it doesn't work. let me check that

Comment: 1. Don't use the `mysql_` methods; they're [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). 2. Don't try to format your JSON yourself, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a normal PHP array containing the values you want, and call `json_encode` to convert it to JSON. Echo that, and parse it on the client.

```
<?php
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $array = array($data['latitude'], $data['longitude'], $data['venue']);
?>

<script>
    var sites = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

Edit: as @kba points out, the `mysql_` methods are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you sql is working fine, then you just need to remove the extras "[" "]", so it will be like this:

```
echo $data['latitude'].", ";
echo $data['longitude'].", ";
echo $data['venue'];
```

Then your javascript array will be working ok

Comment: Why downvote?? It fixes the js array construction, that he was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if u hav a php array **$sites**, u need to add it to js array **sites**

```
<?php
$sit="";
foreach($sites as $ar)
{
    if($sit=="")
    {
        $sit=$ar;
    }
    else
    {
        $sit=$sit.",".$ar;
    }
}
?>
```

in js:

```
var sites = [<?php echo $sit;] ?>;
```

Comment: What if `$sit` contains a ','? Or a ']'?

Comment: its variable to store the values seperated with comma, after all the iteration sit contains all the values in array seperated by comma.

Comment: Oh yeah. But you know what I mean - the PHP string isn't being escaped and could generate invalid JS.

Comment: no its working fine for meeee,,, me using this for generating chart using high charts,,,, no error for me...